# CellForRowAtIndex method not get invoked

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I am fetching some data across the web and want to display it in a table view.

I am fetching this data as soon as the view will appear, using the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

I am performing this fetching process in a background thread and want to display this data in my table view.

So now my problem is that the `cellForRowIndexPath` method is not get called.

What is the solution for this, so that after fetching the data it gets displayed in the table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your TableView links with a delegate and data source, and then try again.

And every time when you come back to your view, write:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i set datasource and delegate to my tableview in viewdidload

Comment: can you show me some more code for- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

to reload table you should call `reloadData`. Also, `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will only get called if you set `dataSource` for your `UITableView`

Comment: my set statement is .... tableView.dataSource=self;      is it correct or do i need to set to something else